# Not all functions were exported using dllexport

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dllimport, dllexport

This question might be similar to 
[DLL Exports: not all my functions are exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791023/dll-exports-not-all-my-functions-are-exported)
but as it was not fully answered there, I have to ask again. Also my case is because of the use of templates and exporting the whole classes slightly different.

Used environment: VS2008, cl9.0.

I have created a dll-project and added about 40 files (each class a file), mainly headers, because a lot of the classes are templates. An example of the heritage would be:

```
// Class1.h
template<class TYPE>
class TInt
{
    // Some member functions here
    // Also a function bool IsValid() const;
};
// Implementation of template here in the header

// Class2.h
#ifndef DllExpImpM
#define DllExpImpM __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DllExpImpM CInt : public TInt<double> 
{ 
    // Some member functions here
};

// Class2.cpp
// Some includes, including "stdafx.h", which sets DllExpImpM 
// to __declspec(dllexport)
template class DllExpImpM TInt<double>;
// Implemenation of CInt
```

So far, it worked fine as long as I used the debug (compile) option. I was able the use the dll project from other projects.

But if the dll projekt is compiled as release (which works fine), I cannot use it from other projects, because the compiler complains that are some missing functions, e.g. that IsValid() in TInt. I used the dependency walker to check it, and indeed, the compiler is right! The member function IsValid() was not exported, along with another function and with a constructor und the destructor. All other member functions of TInt are exported, I can see them using the dependency walker, I can use them from other projects. This also happens in a similar way with one other class.

I then compared the debug dll and the release dll using the dependency walker and winmerge. They are almost identical, just that the release dll is missing a few functions (about 3 %).

I have no idea what is wrong. I know that I do not have a lot information (the whole information is much too big and I yet could not find a simple example that does not work) and to me all sounds a little bit weird. But perhaps anyone out there once had the same problem. I appreciate every idea very much.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to put `template class DllExpImpM TInt<double>;` in header ?

Comment: Thank you for answering, Jarod! The cl9 compiler option /GL caused the problem. See answer of Michael J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for debug, but not release, then you need to identify what is different.  My first guess would be that a `#define` macro or an equivalent `/D` macro us not getting defined or is getting defined wrongly.

Maybe `DllExpImpM` or maybe something else.

If not a macro, then what else changes between builds?

Comment: Thank you for answering, Michael.

Yes, you were right. According to your idea, I searched very accurately for differences between the debug and release compiler options. The option that caused the problem was the /GL (Whole Program Optimization) option which I used for the release mode. If /GL is turned off everything is fine, if /GL is turned on some functions of the dll are not accessable (or even do not exist).

Although I do not understand yet why /GL causes this kind of problem my problem is solved so far. Thank you helping me out!

Comment: @user3144699 - that sounds very odd.  Are the missing functions empty?  /GL is pretty aggressive and can sometimes mess with surprising things but removing (or hiding) a function seems unexpected.

Comment: Following up to note that the [documentation for dumpbin's /exports option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) includes this: "Only the /HEADERS DUMPBIN option is available for use on files produced with the /GL compiler option."

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things I found when I ran into this.

I had the same issue, but taking off the /GL parameter didn't make any difference.

My first test was creating a very simple funcion  - void test () - and trying to export it. That didn't work until I got rid of the whole output directory (x64 in my case) and rebuilt it all. It would guess that some intermediate file was messing my compilation, anyway, I didn't investigate it further.

But there was still one function that wouldn't be exported. I took some time to realize the declaration in the .h file wasn't matching exatly the signature in the .cpp file! I was missing a parameter in the .h file... I don't know why it was even compiling, anyway, fixing that allowed the function to be exported.